# i have a overlapping with active class in php with css style

Tags: php, html, css

```
 <ul>
    <li <?php if($pageid == 1) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=1">HOME</a></li>
    <li <?php if($pageid == 2) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=2">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li <?php if($pageid == 3) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=3">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li <?php if($pageid == 4) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=4">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

that is my nav bar with active links and when i try to style it when is active it dosnt work as i expect.

```
.nav-link {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus {
    color: #ff9328;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff9328;
}

.active{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff9328;
}
```

See images for more clues on what anoys me
[u see home class is active and border is spreed all way as u can see on hover link about border bottom only cover text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edTPs.jpg)

Comment: Ok sorry for my bad english. You see on picture i have posted under 'about' there is border-bottom that covers only text, and on an active class which is 'home' in this example border-bottom is greater than text, i wanna that border-bottom on active link also cover just text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the active styling to the link, not the parent `li`. Change the last CSS code to:

```
.active .nav-link {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff9328;
}
```

Note that this is untested as the question lacks all the relevant CSS styling to test/reproduce this.

Comment: Ok this helped me. Now its all ok. Can i ask u one more question? If i set for example border-bottom: 4px solid #ff9328; and wanna transition option to work from 1px to 4px how to enable it?

Comment: Please accept my answer so it is easily identifiable for other visitors. What is your second question? It is most likely a better idea to ask a new question, AFTER you have tried and tested on your own.

Comment: well i wanna transition from borderr-bottom : 1px to 4px when i click link

Comment: @NebojsaZlatanovic Try something like `.active .nav-link:active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff9328;
}`. However, when you click the link, that will reload the page, so the effect will be gone pretty fast. If this does not work I would advice you to open a new question and ask there. Please accept the answer.

Comment: yeah that click reloads page maybe that is reason why i don't see any animation. Thank You a lot man!